# How to create binding inside custom control automatically?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, binding, custom-controls

I have my custom toolbar control with DependencyProperty `IsBusy`

Here is how I use it:

```
<Controls:myToolbar 
                Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Mode="DataEntry" 
                Status="{Binding State, Converter={StaticResource ViewEditingStateToToolbarStateConverter}}"
                IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}"/>
```

By convention all my VM's inherit from base VM and have IsBusy property. 
So, I KNOW that this property will always be available on VM.

Now I have another 4 properties like this. Instead of adding them to XAML on all my views I want to know how to bind to this `IsBusy` automatically inside control's code so I don't have to bind in XAML?

**EDIT**

Actually, I found answer to my question: [Silverlight: Programmatically binding control properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126490/silverlight-programmatically-binding-control-properties)

Now, my question is:

Is it correct to apply this binding in constructor like this?

```
public myToolbar()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(myToolbar);

            var binding = new Binding("IsBusy") { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };
            this.SetBinding(IsBusyProperty, binding); 
        }
```

Should I check if XAML binding (another binding) exist to this property and not bind? It works either way but I wonder if it's bad for performance, smells, etc?

What about doing this in `onApplyTemplate`. Is that better way?

```
if (GetBindingExpression(IsBusyProperty) == null)
            {
                var binding = new Binding("IsBusy") { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };
                this.SetBinding(IsBusyProperty, binding);
            }
```

Comment: Good point, I'm working the way you do and I never even thought of auto-bind it ;-)

Comment: By the way, I suposse you should make your own "root-grid" to contain all the control's children with those bindings shouldn't you??

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. I do have internal property that auto-detects parent grid. I check for name "LayoutRoot" and if not - just check for any parent grid. Otherwise throw exception so you see it even at design time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be bad if you tried to use this control with a view model which doesn't have the `IsBusy` property, but even then you'll receive just a debug warning in the output window, nothing to worry about.

As to the place of the binding, the constructor is appropriate if the dependency property which you are binding to doesn't perform any actions inside its callback.
But if the property changed callback tries to call such functions as `GetTemplateChild` and retrieve inner controls - then you should move the binding to the `OnApplyTemplate` functions, because only there you can be assured that inner controls exist.

By the way, if your dependency proeprty doesn't have a property changed callback and is used only in the control template like `{TemplateBinding IsBusy}`, you can replace this line by `{Binding IsBusy}`. Something like this, either by using binding or data triggers:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Controls:myToolbar}">
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl x:Name="content" ... />
        <ProgressBar x:name="progress" ... />
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBusy}" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="progress" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </DataTrigger>
```

The idea is simple: `TemplateBinding` is applied to dependency properties of the control, whereas `Binding` is applied to properties of the DataContext object or the view model and they can coexist without problems.

Comment: You are reading my mind :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855709/how-bad-binding-and-converter-errors-should-i-handle-them-somehow

I "kind of" fixed it by adding bindings when specific mode set (which tells me who using control) but still.. Thanks for explaining about Binding vs TemplateBinding! I can't utilize this now, but in other cases it is going to be useful for sure