# How bad binding and converter errors. Should I handle them somehow?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, binding

I have errors like this because my controls self-bind. It doesn't hurt anything as far as I can tell but I wonder if I should worry about this?

> System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error:
>   'CanNavigateLast' property not found on
>   'Infrastructure.Controls.Lookup.LookupViewModel'
>   'Infrastructure.Controls.Lookup.LookupViewModel' (HashCode=21405046).
>   BindingExpression: Path='CanNavigateLast'
>   DataItem='Infrastructure.Controls.Lookup.LookupViewModel'
>   (HashCode=21405046); target element is
>   'Infrastructure.Controls.DitatToolbar' (Name=''); target property is
>   'CanNavigateLast' (type 'System.Boolean')..

Or this. I know it's null and it doesn't seem to cause any problems but I wonder if that's a problem?

> System.Windows.Data Error: 'MS.Internal.Data.DynamicValueConverter'
>   converter failed to convert value 'null' (type 'null');
>   BindingExpression: Path='FilterFrom'
>   DataItem='Infrastructure.Controls.Lookup.FilterBoxRow'
>   (HashCode=57480441); target element is
>   'System.Windows.Controls.NumericUpDown' (Name=''); target property is
>   'Value' (type 'System.Double').. System.InvalidOperationException:
>   Can't convert type null to type System.Double.    at
>   MS.Internal.Data.DynamicValueConverter.Convert(Object value, Type
>   targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)    at
>   System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ConvertToTarget(Object value).

Comment: no but Leaving Errors is like the old saying Garbage IN = Garbage OUT.. you apparently have errors for example Converting type null to double.. can you paste the code that corresponds to these errors so that someone may attempt to help you correct the issue you are having..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you should not have any error like this

**But**

There is nothing to worry about these kind of errors. Invalid bindings don't hurt in any way because they are not treated as exceptions(which cause huge performance hit). There won't be any performance issue or something similar

Although you can see failed bindings through [trace listener](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-snippet-detecting-binding-errors) like you see them in output window of visual studio but in normal app as there will be no trace listeners so there won't be any effect of failed bindings.